# Require dependency of parent project in node

Tags: node.js

As a library I would like to load a dependency of the project that is using me:

```
/main-project
   /dependency-1
   /my-library
```

I would like to do `require('dependency-1')` inside `my-library`. Is there a way to do this in node?

Comment: From within my-library` you would typically do: `require('../dependency-1')` to load `../dependency-1/index.js` (up one level, then down to `dependency-1`) or to look in that directory for a `package.json` (and get details from within that file), but it's not entirely clear what you're trying to do since you don't show the actual .js files you want the `require()` statement to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found was to do something hacky like `require('../dependency-1/main')`